# Eclipse problem with symbol §

Tags: windows, eclipse, ubuntu, symbols, fonts

I'm using Eclipse for programming. In one method of my project i used the String "§". I use a svn repository. If i edit the file with Ubuntu OS the § symbol isnt displayed correctly in the eclipse editor and also in my programm, if I edited it before on Windows. The same is vice versa.

Any hints how to solve this problem? I don't want to always change the symbol manually if I comitted a new version from another OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "Text file encoding" of your sources.
(`Preferences / General / Workspace`)

I would recommend in your case `UTF-8`.

You can also set the default type in `Preferences / General / Content Type / Text / Java source file`

[alt text http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/4341/eclipseencoding.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/4341/eclipseencoding.png)

Comment: Also, once the file encoding is changed you might have to retype the symbols that were broken.

Comment: thanks this solved the problem. But this is really annoying that this isn't the default setting. Now I have to inform all other contributers to the source code to change their settings...

Comment: You can also change these setting only on given project (you have to right click on project and choose Properties).